# merge rows of dataframe and perform weighted sums of two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I have the following dataframe in R.

```
  Sequence occurences response_percent
1 AAAAA        100       0.2
2 BBBBB        100       0.1
3 CCCCC        100       0.8
4 DDDDD        100       0.2
5 AAAAA         50       0.4
```

I want to merge the two rows with the same sequence `AAAAA`. And I want the the `occurences` column of the merged row to be the sum of the two original occurneces: `100+50`, and I want the `response_percent` column of the merged row to be the sum of the two original response_percent weighted by the occurences: `(100*0.2 + 50*0.4)/(100 + 50)`. So the end result after merging should be

```
 Sequence occurences response_percent
1 AAAAA        150       0.26667
2 BBBBB        100       0.1
3 CCCCC        100       0.8
4 DDDDD        100       0.2
```

Any idea on what kind of operations can achieve this using R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `dplyr` after grouping by 'Sequence'

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
   group_by(Sequence) %>%
   summarise(response_percent = sum(occurences * response_percent)/sum(occurences),
            occurences = sum(occurences))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Sequence response_percent occurences
#  <chr>               <dbl>      <int>
#1 AAAAA               0.267        150
#2 BBBBB               0.1          100
#3 CCCCC               0.8          100
#4 DDDDD               0.2          100
```

Or can also use `%*%`

```
%>%
   summarise(response_percent = (occurences %*% response_percent)/sum(occurences))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Sequence = c("AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD", 
"AAAAA"), occurences = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 50L), 
response_percent = c(0.2, 
0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like weighted mean. R has a default function to calculate that.

Using `data.table` we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .(occurence = sum(occurences), 
       response_percent = weighted.mean(response_percent, occurences)), Sequence]

#   Sequence occurence response_percent
#1:    AAAAA       150            0.267
#2:    BBBBB       100            0.100
#3:    CCCCC       100            0.800
#4:    DDDDD       100            0.200
```

Or the same with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Sequence) %>%
  summarise(response_percent = weighted.mean(response_percent, occurences),
            occurences = sum(occurences))
```